# How to make a killer bot

Tags: lua, bots, roblox

I'm actually new to roblox studio and I want to make my own basic shooter game. I know when I publish only one or two will come at the beginning and I don't want them to leave without playing itself. So I decided to create killer bots who play just like players[kill the players, and escape from not getting killed]. Is there any way I can do that because NPC creating is easy but asking them to kill the players is difficult and moreover the NPC's are not counted as players and not shown in the leaderstats. How can I show that?

Comment: Sorry, but an entire AI simulating player behavior is beyond basic programming (assuming it's not part of Roblox already). Let it move around randomly, but slightly towards the player using the pathfinder. When low on health let it move it away. While moving, randomly shoot at the player when there is no intersection. Shooting should not really differ from how the player shoot. For the leaderstats, what happens if you set the leaderstats parent to any humanoid (non player)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But one problem still prevails is that NPC's are not shown on the leaderstats, whereas real players are shown. My problem is that I wish to show the number of kills and deaths in the leaderstats, when the NPC's are themselves not shown there, how can I show the bots stats.

Comment: If my suggestion fails, chances are high that it is (currently) impossible. You can implement your own GUI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using PathFinding won't work that well, so I recommend using a Raycast and Strafing. And if the npc touches player, check if the hit part's parent IS a player and then set its health to 0 or damage his health.

For leaderstats, the roblox sword has a tag called "creator" that is there for KOs. Add the creator tag for the leaderstats to work.